# Animate in div with image when scroll down to the bottom of where the image using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have static images that I want to animate in when the user scrolls to the bottom of where they would be (the bottom of their rectangle).  I've tried using the code:

```
       $(window).on("scroll", function(){
        if($("body").scrollTop() === 500){
            $(window).off("scroll");
            //Do stuff here
            $('.context_right').fadein(4000);
        }
    });
```

With .context_right being the  that contains the image I want to slide in from off the right side of the screen.  I have tested this in Chrome debugger but there is not animation at all and I can't see why it's not being fired when scrolling down.

Answer (score 1):

You're checking if the scroll position of the window is *exactly* equal to 500px. This is likely incorrect. You probably only want to check and see if the user has scrolled *past* 500px.

Consider changing:

```
if($("body").scrollTop() === 500)
```

to:

```
if($("body").scrollTop() >= 500)
```

Also, be careful with this:

```
$(window).off("scroll");
```

If you use any libraries that rely on the scroll event on the window, you would be unbinding all of those events in addition to your own.

Consider refactoring to something like the following:

```
var scrollAnimateIn = function(){
    if($("body").scrollTop() >= 500){
        $(window).off("scroll", scrollAnimateIn);
        //Do stuff here
        $('.context_right').fadein(4000);
    }
};
$(window).on("scroll", scrollAnimateIn);
```